# Find a graph that has a high minimum degree, but low connectivity and edge connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I've been stuck on this for a while. First, some definitions, in case my prof uses different terms than everyone else.

**Minimum degree**: This is equal to the number of edges connected to the vertex that has the least number of edges incident to it.

**Connectivity**: The larges number k, such that the graph is k-connected.

**k-connected**: A graph G is k-connected if there doesn't exist any set of vertices, call it X, such that the size of X is less than k, and G - X is disconnected.

**Edge Connectivity**: The larges value l, such that that there doesn't exist a set of edges, call it F, such that the size of F is less than l, and G - F is disconnected

So the question asks us to find a graph that has a high minimum degree but low connectivity and edge connectivity. I think I've made one with high minimum degree and low connectivity
[image]

The above is 1-connected but has minimum degree of 4.

However, I can't figure out a graph that has high minimum degree but low edge connectivity.
Would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

I made this graph on https://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=3550
EDIT: I made a mistake. The four corner vertices had degrees of 2. This following graph is the graph I was looking for:
[image]

It has a minimum degree of four. A connectivity of 1 and edge connectivity of 1. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would separating $A$ into two nodes connected by one edge work? Also, the minimum degree of your graph is $2$ at each of the four corner nodes.

[image: Actual Example Graph]

The graph with the largest minimum degree, lowest edge connectivity, and lowest vertex connectivity is formed by connecting two complete graphs with one singular edge like a bridge.

Comment: Yes. I can't beleive I didn't think of that. I need to take a break... Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, the edit you made gives a connectivity of 3.

Comment: My bad. All I need to do is remove the top and bottom edges and put them somewhere else.